# Parsing JSON in Retrofit using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
 "FLYWEIGHT": [
 {
 "name": "Henry Cejudo"
 },
 {
 "name": "Sergio Borg"
 },.........], 
 {...},
 ...]}
```

I'm struggling to parse this with Gson. I have the following structure for `UfcRank` and `FighterList`:

```
public class UfcRank {

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
}


public class FighterList {

@SerializedName("FLYWEIGHT")
public List<UfcRank> FLYWEIGHT;

}
```

I use `retrofit` to parse through:

```
RankingsApi service = RankingsRestAdapter.getRetrofitInstance().create(RankingsApi.class);
Call<Fighterlist> call = service.getRankingsApi();

call.enqueue(new Callback<FighterList>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<FighterList> call, Response<FighterList> response) {
    FighterList data = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().toString(), FighterList.class);
```

}

I have the following structure for `RankingsApi` and `RankingsRestAdapter`:

```
public interface RankingsApi {

@GET("last_ready_run/data?api_key=XXXXXX")
Call<FighterList> getRankingsApi();

}

public class RankingsRestAdapter {

public static final String RANKINGS_URL = "XXXXXXX"
public static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

if (retrofit == null) {
    retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(RANKINGS_URL)
    .addConverterFactor(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
}
return retrofit;
}
}
```

Now I receive the error:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but Was STRIng at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Is this due to how I'm structuring the `UfcRank` and `FighterList` classes?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have used `GsonConverterFactory` while building `Retrofit` instance, Gson parsing is already used and it provides you with the reference of your model class directly. You should not parse again.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<FighterList> call, Response<FighterList> response) {
    if(response.isSuccessful() {
        FighterList data = response.body();
    } else {
        // Handle error.
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I access the individual elements in the list? I'm getting "com.example.....FighterList@257bd8" when I call "data.toString()". Thanks!

Comment: Don't convert it to String either. Directly access the returned list using `data.FLYWEIGHT;`